# Creating a MS Word or PDF doc in Delphi 7 Websnap

Tags: delphi, ms-word

I do programming with Delphi 7 as a hobby and have done a number of programs but am now trying to develop a web based one for the first time using Websnap. I used this example found on the net http://read.pudn.com/downloads27/ebook/87707/Online%2BPDF%20Docs/Borland/Tutorials/WebSnap.pdf and adapted it a bit for my own needs but would like to use some of the info in the database to produce an invoice with word or pdf. I do have the code to produce a Word doc in a normal Delhi app but have no idea how to use it in the websnap app.
Please help. I'm not a pro with Delhi so need it to be as simple as possible.
Thanks

Comment: Use SynPDF to make a PDF file.

Comment: You can use your normal Delphi app to create the Word document and communicate with the WebSnap server over an internal network connection: embed a HTTP server in the Delphi application. (and try to convert it into a service application, or a console program)